# Parse and evaluate a mathematical expression, but only one step

Tags: math

I've been looking for libraries, binaries or APIs that can evaluate an arithmetic expression - say, `(3/(1+1))^4`, but only for one step - meaning that the output would be `(3/2)^4`, rather than `5,0625`.
Is there any such software, or can it be done?

Comment: I'm not aware of any that stop short of completing the task. But I would think that most solutions that you can find out there are recursive and, therefore, would be easily modified to do what you want. Did you have a particular programming language in mind, or is this a hypothetical question?

Comment: This is more of a hypothetical question, I'd say - I don't have any programming language in mind in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the general answer is that you are looking for a computer algebra or symbolic computation system. A web search for those terms should turn up a lot of resources.

Specifically about carrying out step-by-operations, I don't know of any system to do it out of the box; the problem is that computer algebra systems tend to apply lots of rules to get a result which is then displayed, but you want to control it so that it does only one step at a time.

I know Maxima cannot go step by step. Maybe take a look at Sympy (I have no idea whether it can either).